# the 'disappearance' of my data in R

Tags: r

```
 data(iris)
 library(RSNNS)
 library(clue)
 iris = iris[sample(1:nrow(iris),length(1:nrow(iris))),1:ncol(iris)]
 irisValues= iris[,1:4]
 irisTargets = decodeClassLabels(iris[,5])
 iris = splitForTrainingAndTest(irisValues, irisTargets, ratio=0.4)
 km<-kmeans(iris$inputsTrain,3)
 save(km,file=”km”)
```

when I load km,that is `load('km')` in another program.
And type in `iris$inputsTrain`or `iris$inputsTest` it shows `>NULL`

Comment: It seems that you forgot `.RData` in `save(km,file=”km”)`, shouldnt it be `save(km,file=”km.RData”)`?.

Comment: @Jilber Thanks. I have tried your method. But the problem remains to be unsolved.

Answer (score 1):

You saved an object called `km` in the file `"km"`. You didn't save your dataset called `iris`. What did you expect?

Comment: I have divided my dataset into 2 parts, `iris$inputsTrain` and `iris$inputsTest`. And `iris$inputsTrain` is used in this program. I want to use `iris$inputsTest` in another program to make predictions. So I expect when I type `iris$inputsTest` in another program,there can  be the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save all the variables in the environment, you should use:

```
save.image(file="myfile.RData")
```

that is basically a shortcut for `save(list = ls(all = TRUE),file="myfile.RData")` i.e. call `save` passing the list of all the variables.